# Add array to another array with keeping the same amount of indices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, algorithm

I have array A and I am trying to concat it to array B while array B keeps the same amount of indices.

for example:

```
const array_A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const array_B = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
```

the result should look like this

```
const result = [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0];
```

I tried this approach

```
const result = array_A.concat(array_B);
console.log(result);
```

but then I got array of 11 indices which I only want array of 7 indices.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the second array and check if the first array has a value at that index.

```
array_B.map((n, i) => array_A[i] ?? n)
```

If the value at an index can be null / undefined, then the [`??` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) will ignore it and use the `array_B` value. In that case, you can check if `array_A` has that specific index using the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) opeartor

```
array_B.map((n, i) => i in array_A ? array_A[i] : n)
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
const array_A = [1, 2, 3, 4],
      array_B = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      output1 = array_B.map((n, i) => array_A[i] ?? n),
      output2 = array_B.map((n, i) => i in array_A ? array_A[i] : n)
      
console.log(...output1)
console.log(...output2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like below:

```js
const array_A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const array_B = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

for (let i = array_A.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  array_B.pop()
  array_B.unshift(array_A[i])
}

console.log(array_B)
```

Poping out last element of second array ie. `array_B` using `pop()` then inserting element from `array_A` to `array_B` from front using unshift() method. Must Loop with respect to element present in `array_A`

Comment: Note that this mutates `array_B`.  Perhaps that is what's desired, but I wouldn't do so unless I was absolutely certain that I have no other use for `array_B`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use for or forEach loop on  Array_A then you can replace value of Array_B with value of Array_A

```js
const A = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const B = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];

A.forEach((val, i) => {
  B[i] = val;
})

console.log(B) // [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

Comment: OP mentioned that *"array B keeps the same amount of indices*". So, if the A array is longer, it will increase the length of the B array.

Comment: we can add one more condition , we will iterate Array_A only till length of Array_B

Answer (score 0):

We don't usually think about [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for arrays, but it works well with them.  We can do this, then by stripping our overwriting array to the number of elements in our base array and then doing an `Object .assingn` either as `Object .assign ([...b], a .slice (0, b .length))` or `Object .assign ([], b, a .slice (0, b .length))`, as you choose:

```js
const partialMerge = (a, b) => Object .assign ([...b], a .slice (0, b .length))

console .log (partialMerge ([1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))
  //=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0]
console .log (partialMerge ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))
  //=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
console .log (partialMerge ([ ,  , 3, 4], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))
  //=> [0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```